# How can I avoid to repeat myself in Laravel (4) Controllers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I feel I repeat myself in Laravel (4) controllers. For example, I need some `$variables` for every view. I get them from cache or database. Because geting and processing them take some lines of codes (between 5-100 lines), I repeat them in every controller function. This is especially a problem when updating functions (They increase complexity).

How can I avoid this without any negative effect?

Note: `$variables` are mostly not global variables.

Comment: You could abstract this out into a class method that your controller loads via its constructor. This would mean writing the code once but calling it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about this, but it sounds like the variables are more specific to your View's than your controllers.

You can easily share variables across your views in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`.

```
view()->share('variables', function(){
    //you can share whatever you want here and it will be availble in all views.
});
```

Comment: I see, but most of the variables are user specific, for example coming user's subscriptions variable. So, they are mostly not global.

Comment: Ohgodwhy, which one in Thomas' answer is better, do you think?

Comment: @user2356198 I would suggest using a Trait, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

- You can create a static helper class (all static functions)
  e.g.

  ```
  class VarHelper {
      public static function getVars() {
          return [];
      }
  }
  ```
- You can create your own basecontroller you extend in every other controller
  e.g.

  ```
  class MyController extends Controller {
      public function getVars() {
          return [];
      }
  }

  class BlaController extends MyController {
      public function doBla() {
          $vars = $this->getVars();
      }
  }
  ```
- creating the function inside the controller and call it in the other functions
- use a [Trait](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Traits.html)
- And probably more solutions

Comment: Thomas, should `VarHelper` class be `BaseController` extended or bare? It seems to me the second choice is more elegant? Which one is better for performance, first or second?

Comment: I think it does barely matter for performance in the real world. `Varhelper` is just a static helper class that extends nothing!

Comment: I used BaseController, but when I call `getVars` function from `doBla` function, it results in 404 error :(

Comment: if you did it right, you should be able to use the functions from the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `trait` with a method to set all of the necessary variables.

```
use View;

trait SharedControllerVariables {

    public function loadUsersSubscription() {
        View::make('user_subscription_variable_1', [...data...]);
        View::make('user_subscription_variable_2', [...data...]);
    }
}
```

Then call it in your controller constructor:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

    use SharedControllerVariables;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->loadUsersSubscription();
    }
}
```